# Bug in StringIO module python using numpy

Tags: python, stringio

Very simple code:

```
import StringIO
import numpy as np
c = StringIO.StringIO()
c.write("1 0")
a = np.loadtxt(c)
print a
```

I get an empty array + warning that c is an empty file.

I fixed this by adding:

```
d=StringIO.StringIO(c.getvalue())
a = np.loadtxt(d)
```

I think such a thing shouldn't happen, what is happening here?

Comment: "There's a bug in a standard Python module" should _not_ be your first assumption. Also, what is your question?

Comment: why is that happening?

Comment: why does it work like that?

Comment: Why is that happening? Put that in your actual question, not as a comment.

Comment: You need to seek to first , c.seek(0); a = numpy.loadtxt(c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringIO` is a file-like object. As such it has behaviors consistent with a file. There is a notion of a file pointer - the current position within the file. When you write data to a `StringIO` object the file pointer is adjusted to the end of the data. When you try to read it, the file pointer is already at the end of the buffer, so no data is returned.

To read it back you can do one of two things:

- Use `StringIO.getvalue()` as you already discovered. This returns the
  data from the beginning of the buffer, leaving the file pointer unchanged.
- Use `StringIO.seek(0)` to reposition the file pointer to the start of
  the buffer and then calling `StringIO.read()` to read the data.

**Demo**

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO

>>> s = StringIO()
>>> s.write('hi there')
>>> s.read()
''
>>> s.tell()    # shows the current position of the file pointer
8
>>> s.getvalue()
'hi there'
>>> s.tell()
8
>>> s.read()
''
>>> s.seek(0)
>>> s.tell()
0
>>> s.read()
'hi there'
>>> s.tell()
8
>>> s.read()
''
```

There is one exception to this. If you provide a value at the time that you create the `StringIO` the buffer will be initialised  with the value, but the file pointer will positioned at the start of the buffer:

```
>>> s = StringIO('hi there')
>>> s.tell()
0
>>> s.read()
'hi there'
>>> s.read()
''
>>> s.tell()
8
```

And that is why it works when you use

```
d=StringIO.StringIO(c.getvalue())
```

because you are initialising the `StringIO` object at creation time, and the file pointer is positioned at the beginning of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the 'position' of the file object is at the end of the file after the write. So when numpy reads it, it reads from the end of the file to the end, which is nothing.

Seek to the beginning of the file and then it works:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO()
>>> s.write("1 2")
>>> s.read()
''
>>> s.seek(0)
>>> s.read()
'1 2'
```